# Download file from webpage which does not have a download link

Tags: python, html, file

I am trying to download this excel file using Python.

http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/MarketWatch.aspx?expandable=2. The excel file is on the right side in the box which says "Top Turnovers - All Market".

[image]

I am not an HTML expert but usually all files embedded in web I see has a download link (when I rightclick on download button). This one is just an image of excel icon with no pointer to the download link. However, when you click on it a file is downloaded. This could be a common HTML feature but I am not able to figure it out where the file is located. Even the source code is pointing out to icon image.

However my end goal is to able to download this file through python. I thought I could use beautifulsoup and with my limited knowledge on that I think I need to point to a download link. In this case I do not have one. So is there some other way to do it? May be I am missing something basic but any help on how to download this file would be great. I am not looking for a full code or even a working code. Just some pointers on how to go about it and which package to use. I can find my way once I know what I am suppose to use.

Comment: You should use the debugger of your browser (press F12) and see where the request goes to.

Comment: I did that before positing this. It only shows where the icon image is located but not the actual file behind it. (Like I said I do not know if it is a common HTML feature or a really well programmed hack to hide the location of the file)

Comment: If there is no request, then the files comes from Java Script, either it is loaded before, or it is created in memory dynamically.

Comment: So do you have any suggestion on how to download this file in a python code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task of clicking we can do it through the javascript, for this use selenium and the chromedriver.

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
url = "http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/MarketWatch.aspx?expandable=2"
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
chrome.get(url)

chrome.execute_script("document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_imgDownload').click();")
```

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I will try that from my personal machine and comment on how it went. I am having some directory location error problem from my work machine.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: Windows. The error I am getting is "WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home"

Comment: The error message tells you to add the location of the file to the PATH:http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: Or For windows, please have the chromedriver.exe placed under <Install Dir>/Python27/Scripts/

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks!